# group the result fetched through find - laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table named **generalmembers**. I have col named **designation_name** which I want to group.

The problem I face is that I using the Eloquent relations which brings result based on the ID,

```
$generalmembers = Generalpresident::findOrFail($id)->generalmembers;
```

The above query yields me the result but how do I group the result based on designation_name,

```
@foreach ($generalmembers as $generalmember)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{$generalmember->first_name}}
        </td>
        <td> 
            {{$generalmember->generaldesignations->designation_name}} 
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Relations:

```
class Generalpresident extends Model
{
    public function generalmembers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Generalmembers', 'president_id' , 'id');
    }
}


class Generalmembers extends Model
{
   public function generalpresidents(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Generalpresident','president_id');
    }
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you show me Table Relation?

Comment: @Amy  I have added the relations to the question. kindly check

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to group `generalmembers` by `designation_name` or `generalpresidents`? Also, can you explain how you want to use the data?

Comment: The designation_name is in the generalmembers table. I want to group the result based on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who did take time to respond my question. I really appreciate it.

I did found out a workaround, Instead of working on the controller, I took it to the blade.

```
@foreach ($generalmembers->groupby('designation_name') as $generalmember)
     @foreach ($generalmember as $item)
       {{$item->first_name}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I do appreciate if this one is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$generalmembers = Generalpresident::findOrFail($id)->generalmembers()->groupBy('designation_name');
```

Comment: I tried tit earlier, getting this error,
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::isEmpty()

Comment: My Apologies, I was using the  @if (!$generalmembers->isEmpty())  conditon. I now removed it. But the above query down't yield any result

Comment: findOrFail($id) takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it throws an error...why should you put a groupBy on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this if you expecting multiple items:

```
$generalmembers = Generalpresident::with('generalmembers')
                                  ->where('id','=', $id)
                                  ->groupBy('designation_name')
                                  ->get();
```

Comment: where does I join generalmember table. Because the designation_name is in generalmember

Comment: Thanks Alphy for the query, the query yields result from the Generalpresident but not generalmembers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Generalmembers::whereHas('generalpresidents',function($q){
  $q->where('id',2);
})->select('designation_name')->groupBy('designation_name)->get();
```